# django - multiple queries into one

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, geodjango

I want to find the `Records` with a certain `tag` within 100 mile radius. I have two queries that work independently (see below) but I don't know how to put them together.

Also `Records` model has a foreign key pointing to the `GeoLocation` model called `geo_location`. I want to be able to show fields from both models `(Records` and `GeoLocation`) in one shot. I tried with `.select_related()` on the `GeoLocation` query below but for some reason I only get it to show the `GeoLocation` model fields and not the additional `Records` model fields as I expected.

```
tag_search = Records.objects.filter(tags__slug__in=[tag])
geo_search = GeoLocation.objects.select_related().filter(srid2163__distance_lte=(pnt, D(mi=100))).distance(pnt)
```

Any ideas?

---

These are my models:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class GeoLocation (models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    long = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    srid2163 = models.PointField(blank=True,srid=2163)
    server_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.lat, self.long, self.server_time)


class Records(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    message_body = models.TextField()
    server_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    geo_location = models.ForeignKey(GeoLocation, related_name='geoloc')


    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.title, self.message_body, self.server_time)
```

For the `tags` field in the `Records` model I'm using [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit).

Comment: 1. Please show your actual models. 2. Why are you using `in` with a single-element list, rather than just `tags__slug=tag`? 3. How are you seeing that your `GeoLocation` objects aren't pre-fetching the related `Record`?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  1. See the models above. 2. That's because I'm using djago-taggit for the tags field to search for the tags. 3. I tested in my template like this {% for geo in geo_search %} {{geo.lat}}{{geo.title}} {% endfor %}. I can see the content of {{geo.lat}} but not the {{geo.title}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong here.

Firstly, you've misunderstood what `select_related()` does. It doesn't bring the fields from the related model into the current one. Instead, it just pre-fetches the related instance, so that doing the `model_instance.foreignkey_field.field_on_related_model` doesn't cause another db hit.

Secondly, your models contradict what you originally said about the foreignkey. You said it was from GeoLocation to Records, but the model definitions show that is the other way round. `select_related` does not work in that direction - there is no way, given your current models, to query GeoLocation and get the related Records in one go. However, you *can* query Records and get the related GeoLocations.

(Thirdly, your answer to my comment about the use of the single-element `in` lookup is completely irrelevant. Use `tags_slug=tag`.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how the select_related works and also the issue with the tags filter. You are right I screwed up when I said it was from GeoLocation to Records when it was the other way - sorry about that. I edited the question to reflect what I should have asked in the first place. Still one question remains. Is there a way to find Records with a certain tag within 100 mile radius considering the above models? Thank you for your time and help.